# Arduino Project Simon Says

Tags: arduino

I have to make a project for school but our teacher can't help us. I was wondering if one of you would like to help me with a problem I have on my project of Arduino.

I want a button in my project that starts my completly game including my starttune, etc. Now it starts automaticly and that is not what my assignment is saysing. It has to start all of it when i push that button. Currently I have the following code for my game self.

Thanks in advance

```
    /*Simon Says 
*/
#include <Tone.h> //Librarie die ik zelf heb toegevoegd om de gebluiden van de buzzer/luidspreker beter te kunnen behandelen Tone speakerpin; int starttune[] = { NOTE_E5, NOTE_E5, 0, NOTE_E5, 0, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, 0, NOTE_G5, 0, 0, 0, NOTE_G4, 0, 0, 0, NOTE_C5, 0, 0, NOTE_G4, 0, 0, NOTE_E4, 0, 0, NOTE_A4, 0, NOTE_B4, 0, NOTE_AS4, NOTE_A4, 0, NOTE_G4, NOTE_E5, NOTE_G5, NOTE_A5, 0, NOTE_F5, NOTE_G5, 0, NOTE_E5, 0,NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_B4, 0, 0, NOTE_C5, 0, 0, NOTE_G4, 0, 0, NOTE_E4, 0, 0, NOTE_A4, 0, NOTE_B4, 0, NOTE_AS4, NOTE_A4, 0, NOTE_G4, NOTE_E5, NOTE_G5, NOTE_A5, 0, NOTE_F5, NOTE_G5, 0, NOTE_E5, 0,NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_B4, 0, 0 }; int duurToon2[] = { 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,

12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,

9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,

12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,

9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 }; int note[]
= {NOTE_C4, NOTE_C4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5}; int duurToon[] = {100, 100, 100, 300, 100, 300}; int button[] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //The four button input pins int ledpin[] = {8, 9, 10, 11};  // LED pins int levelSpel = 0;  // levelSpel counter int buttonstate = 0; // button state checker int randomArray[100]; //Intentionally long to store up to 100 inputs (doubtful anyone will get this far) int inputArray[100];  

int score; int highscore;

void setup()  {   Serial.begin(9600);   speakerpin.begin(12); // speaker is on pin 12


  for(int x=0; x<4; x++)  // LED pins are outputs, Range altijd 1 optellen tot aan 4, elke noemer gaat men overlopen   {
    pinMode(ledpin[x], OUTPUT);   }
     for(int x=0; x<4; x++)    {
    pinMode(button[x], INPUT_PULLUP);  // button pins are inputs
    digitalWrite(button[x], HIGH);  // enable internal pullup; buttons start in high position; logic reversed   }

  randomSeed(analogRead(0)); //Added to generate "more randomness" with the randomArray for the output function   for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 13; thisNote ++) {
     // play the next note:
     speakerpin.play(starttune[thisNote]);
     // hold the note:
     if (thisNote==0 || thisNote==2 || thisNote==4 || thisNote== 6)
     {
       digitalWrite(ledpin[0], HIGH);
     }
     if (thisNote==1 || thisNote==3 || thisNote==5 || thisNote== 7 || thisNote==9 || thisNote==11)
     {
       digitalWrite(ledpin[1], HIGH);
     }
     if (thisNote==8 || thisNote==12)
     {
       digitalWrite(ledpin[2], HIGH);
     }  
     if (thisNote==10)
     {   
       digitalWrite(ledpin[3], HIGH);
     }
     delay(duurToon2[thisNote]*10);
     // stop for the next note:
     speakerpin.stop();
     digitalWrite(ledpin[0], LOW);
     digitalWrite(ledpin[1], LOW);
     digitalWrite(ledpin[2], LOW);
     digitalWrite(ledpin[3], LOW);
     delay(25);
    }   delay(1000); }   void loop()  {    
    for (int y=0; y<=99; y++)   {
    //function for generating the array to be matched by the player
    digitalWrite(ledpin[0], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[1], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[2], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[3], HIGH);

    for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 6; thisNote ++) {
     // play the next note:
     speakerpin.play(note[thisNote]);
     // hold the note:
     delay(duurToon[thisNote]);
     // stop for the next note:
     speakerpin.stop();
     delay(25);
    }

    digitalWrite(ledpin[0], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[1], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[2], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[3], LOW);
    delay(1000);

    for (int y=levelSpel; y <= levelSpel; y++)
    { //Limited by the levelSpel variable
      int sensorValue = analogRead(A2); //ophalen waarde van POTmeter
      int MaalPunten = (sensorValue/1024.0)*5; //Formule omzetting naar VOLT, dus uitkomst = spanning
      MaalPunten += 1; // +1 toevoegen omdat spanning 0 kan zijn maar dan krijg je ook 0 punten
      score = score + y * MaalPunten; //score wordt vermeerderd met het geslaadge level vermenigvuldigd met het aantal Volts
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("----------------------------------------------");
      Serial.println("Puntengraad:");
      Serial.println(String(MaalPunten));
      Serial.println("----------------------------------------------");
      Serial.println("Huidige score: "); //Some serial output to follow along
      Serial.println(score);
      Serial.print("Highscore ");
      Serial.println(highscore);
      Serial.println("----------------------------------------------");
      Serial.print("Level ");
      Serial.print(y+1);
      Serial.println("");
      randomArray[y] = random(1, 5); //Assigning a random number (1-4) to the randomArray[y], y being the levelSpel count
      for (int x=0; x <= levelSpel; x++)
      {


        for(int y=0; y<4; y++)
        {

          if (randomArray[x] == 1 && ledpin[y] == 8) 
          {  //if statements to display the stored values in the array
            digitalWrite(ledpin[y], HIGH);
            speakerpin.play(NOTE_G3, 100);
            delay(400);
            digitalWrite(ledpin[y], LOW);
            delay(100);
          }

          if (randomArray[x] == 2 && ledpin[y] == 9) 
          {
            digitalWrite(ledpin[y], HIGH);
            speakerpin.play(NOTE_A3, 100);
            delay(400);
            digitalWrite(ledpin[y], LOW);
            delay(100);
          }

          if (randomArray[x] == 3 && ledpin[y] == 10) 
          {
            digitalWrite(ledpin[y], HIGH);
            speakerpin.play(NOTE_B3, 100);
            delay(400);
            digitalWrite(ledpin[y], LOW);
            delay(100);
          }

          if (randomArray[x] == 4 && ledpin[y] == 11) 
          {
            digitalWrite(ledpin[y], HIGH);
            speakerpin.play(NOTE_C4, 100);
            delay(400);
            digitalWrite(ledpin[y], LOW);
            delay(100);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    input();   } }

    void input() { //Function for allowing user input and checking input against the generated array

  for (int x=0; x <= levelSpel;)   { //Statement controlled by levelSpel count

    for(int y=0; y<4; y++)
    {

      buttonstate = digitalRead(button[y]);

      if (buttonstate == LOW && button[y] == 2)
      { //Checking for button push
        digitalWrite(ledpin[0], HIGH);
        speakerpin.play(NOTE_G3, 100);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(ledpin[0], LOW);
        inputArray[x] = 1;
        delay(250);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print("Rood ");
        if (inputArray[x] != randomArray[x]) { //Checks value input by user and checks it against
          fail();                              //the value in the same spot on the generated array
       // Serial.print(randomArray[x]);
        }                                      //The fail function is called if it does not match
        x++;
      }
       if (buttonstate == LOW && button[y] == 3)
      {
        digitalWrite(ledpin[1], HIGH);
        speakerpin.play(NOTE_A3, 100);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(ledpin[1], LOW);
        inputArray[x] = 2;
        delay(250);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print("Geel ");
        if (inputArray[x] != randomArray[x]) {
          fail();
        }
        x++;
      }

      if (buttonstate == LOW && button[y] == 4)
      {
        digitalWrite(ledpin[2], HIGH);
        speakerpin.play(NOTE_B3, 100);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(ledpin[2], LOW);
        inputArray[x] = 3;
        delay(250);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print("Groen ");
        if (inputArray[x] != randomArray[x]) {
          fail();
        }
        x++;
      }

      if (buttonstate == LOW && button[y] == 5)
      {
        digitalWrite(ledpin[3], HIGH);
        speakerpin.play(NOTE_C4, 100);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(ledpin[3], LOW);
        inputArray[x] = 4;
        delay(250);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print("Blauw ");
        if (inputArray[x] != randomArray[x]) 
        {
          fail();
        }
        x++;
      }
    }   }   delay(500);   levelSpel++; //Increments the levelSpel count, also the last action before starting the output function over again }

void fail() { //Function used if the player fails to match the sequence
    for (int y=0; y<=2; y++)   { //Flashes lights for failure

    digitalWrite(ledpin[0], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[1], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[2], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[3], HIGH);
    speakerpin.play(NOTE_G3, 300);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[0], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[1], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[2], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledpin[3], LOW);
    speakerpin.play(NOTE_C3, 300);
    delay(200);

    if (score > highscore){
        highscore = score;
      }   }   delay(500);   levelSpel = -1; //Resets levelSpel value so the game starts over without need for a reset button }
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm sorry i don't read all your code, but why not use just a while loop in the beginning? something like this:

```
int Push_Button = 2;
void setup()  {   
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(Push_Button,INPUT);
bool on = digitalRead(Push_Button);
while(!on)
{
  on = digitalRead(Push_Button);
  delay(50);
}
...
}
```

i hope i get what you want to do...

good day!

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping but it doesn't work... If I press the button, nothing works...

Comment: if you connect the button to pin to in one side and to vdd in the other side?

Comment: * did you connect the button to pin 2 in one side and the other to vdd?